# Scan directory using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scripting, activex

I know that there are some issues with doing this in a web application however I'm just writing my own script for my own PC and I'm writing in javascript.  I know that you can get a file system object by calling:

```
var Fo = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Is there a method that will let me browse for a particular folder that I want?  I haven't used javascript before so I'm not sure what to look for really.

Thanks

EDIT: I misspoke.  Apparently what I'm using is JScript which is not exactly the same thing as javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.  Once I knew I was looking for JScript...

```
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var lib;
lib = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0,"Select Library Folder",0);
```

Comment: As a newbie to javascript, keep in mind that you must adapt your code to the different browsers!

Comment: Not running it in a browser, just running it on my computer by double clicking the JScript file

Comment: Embarassing, but I didnt even know you could do that.  Who is the javascript newbie now ha! - So if you put alert("Hello World"); into a .js file, you can just double click the file and it will alert hello world?

Comment: @Chris: No, `alert` works only in browsers. In JScript for Windows Script Host, you would use `WScript.Echo("Hello World");`

Answer (score 1):

Code to call the **folder dialog box**:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function getFolder(){
  return showModalDialog("folderDialog.html","","width:400px;height:400px;resizeable:yes;");
}
</SCRIPT>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="yourFieldName"><input type="button" value="Browse..." onclick="this.form.yourFieldName.value=getFolder()">
```

**folderDialog.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Browse Folders</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
var currentFolder="";
function GetDriveList(){
  var fso, obj, n, e, item, arr=[];
try {
  fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
}
catch(er) {
  alert('Could not load Drives. The ActiveX control could not be started.');
  cancelFolder();
}

  e = new Enumerator(fso.Drives);
  for(;!e.atEnd();e.moveNext()){
    item = e.item();
    obj = {letter:"",description:""};
    obj.letter = item.DriveLetter;
    if (item.DriveType == 3) obj.description = item.ShareName;
    else if (item.IsReady) obj.description = item.VolumeName;
    else obj.description = "[Drive not ready]";
    arr[arr.length]=obj;
  }
  return(arr);
}
function GetSubFolderList(fld){
  var e, arr=[];
  var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var f = fso.GetFolder(fld.toString());
  var e = new Enumerator(f.SubFolders);
  for(;!e.atEnd();e.moveNext()){
    arr[arr.length]=e.item().Name;
  }
  return(arr);
}
function loadDrives(){
  var drives=GetDriveList(),list="";
  for(var i=0;i<drives.length;i++){
    list+="<div onclick=\"loadList('"+drives[i].letter+':\\\\\')" class="folders" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseout="unhighlight(this)">'+drives[i].letter+':\\ - '+ drives[i].description+'</div>';
  }
  document.getElementById("path").innerHTML='<a href="" onclick="loadDrives();return false" title="My Computer">My Computer</a>\\';
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML=list;
  currentFolder="";
}
function loadList(fld){
  var path="",list="",paths=fld.split("\\");
  var divPath=document.getElementById("path");
  var divList=document.getElementById("list");
  for(var i=0;i<paths.length-1;i++){
    if(i==paths.length-2){
      path+=paths[i]+' \\';
    }else{
      path+="<a href=\"\" onclick=\"loadList('";
      for(var j=0;j<i+1;j++){
        path+=paths[j]+"\\\\";
      }
      path+='\');return false">'+paths[i]+'</a> \\ ';
    }
  }
  divPath.innerHTML='<a href="" onclick="loadDrives();return false">My Computer</a> \\ '+path;
  divPath.title="My Computer\\"+paths.toString().replace(/,/g,"\\");
  currentFolder=paths.toString().replace(/,/g,"\\");

  var subfolders=GetSubFolderList(fld);
  for(var j=0;j<subfolders.length;j++){
    list+="<div onclick=\"loadList('"+(fld+subfolders[j]).replace(/\\/g,"\\\\")+'\\\\\')" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseout="unhighlight(this)" title="'+subfolders[j]+'" class="folders">'+subfolders[j]+"</div>";
  }
  divList.innerHTML=list;
  resizeList();
  divPath.scrollIntoView();
}
function resizeList(){
  var divList=document.getElementById("list");
  var divPath=document.getElementById("path");
  if(document.body.clientHeight>0 && divPath.offsetHeight>0){
    divList.style.height=document.body.clientHeight-divPath.scrollHeight;
  }
}
function highlight(div){
  div.className="folderButton";
}
function unhighlight(div){
  div.className="folders";
}
function selectFolder(){
  window.returnValue=currentFolder;
  window.close();
}
function cancelFolder(){
  window.returnValue="";
  window.close();
}
-->
</SCRIPT>
<style>
#header{
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
#path{
  position:relative;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px;
}
#list{
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  overflow:auto;
}
.folders{
  padding: 1px;
  border-top: solid 1px white;
  border-left: solid 1px white;
  border-right: solid 1px white;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  cursor: hand;
  pointer: hand;
  background-color: white;
}
.folderButton{
  padding: 0px;
  border-style: outset;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color:;
  cursor: hand;
  pointer: hand;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
A{
  color:blue;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:3px;
}
A:hover{
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  padding:1px;
  border-style: outset;
  border-width: 2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="loadDrives()" onresize="resizeList()" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" scroll=no>
<form>
<div id="container">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="header">
    <tr>
      <td><div id="path"></div></td>
      <td align="right" width="1%" nowrap>
        <input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectFolder()"><input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancelFolder()">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="list">You must allow the ActiveX control to run in order to use this dialog.</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```